# How can I grant windows permissions at the file level via C# app?

Tags: c#, windows

I have read several Stack posts and other articles regarding how to grant permissions to a folder or a file via a c# application, but I have been unable to do it successfully from my C# app.

Here is my use case: My c# app downloads a bunch of CSV files via `AZCopy` (a free Azure Blob storage utility). AZCopy dumps the downloaded files into a folder I created on the server (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter) named **CSV**. The CSV folder has permissions wide open, and set to have all child objects inherit those wide open permissions. Yet when AZCopy writes the files, the permissions are minimal, such that a downstream process (MSSQL `BULKINSERT`) is unable to read them.

1. I login to the server with my account that has ADMIN permissions on the server.
2. I run my .NET/C# EXE, which internally calls `Process.Start(startInfo)` to run AZCopy.
3. AZCopy grabs the files from a remote azure blob storage server and writes them into my CSV folder with minimal permissions.
4. I tried running the EXE as Admin - makes no difference. CSV files are written with minimal permissions always.
5. I tried granting extra permissions to the files after they are written.
6. I tried adding a manifest file to my .NET project with `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` in it. Made no difference.
7. I tried granting permissions programmatically at the folder level instead of the file level - didn't work. (The CSV folder already has full, wide open permissions, so I didn't expect much from this attempt.)

So here is what I have tried in the source code:

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

It executes without errors, but does not change the permissions on the files. So I tried this:

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone",FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,AccessControlType.Allow));    
dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

Again it executes without errors, but does not change the permissions on the files.

So then I opened a command shell on the server and ran this manually:

```
ICACLS "C:\Toyota\Importer\CSV\84834945.csv" /grant "Everyone":F
```

That works perfectly! But I still need it done programmatically from within my .NET exe. So in the c# I loop through the files and run that same exact ICACLS command against each file (again with `Process.Start(startInfo)`). No errors, it reports success...but permissions are unchanged on the files.

It seems like when attempting this within a .NET app, it appears successful, but the OS ignores the permissions update request.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What permissions _exactly_ are set on the files when AZCopy finishes? What user runs the AZCopy process? What user runs the downstream BULKINSERT process? Can those user accounts be harmonized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

After the AZCopy download and before the BULKINSERT, I was doing this:

```
public static void FormatCSV(string csvFilePath) {
 bool foundFooter = false;
 string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

 using(var sr = new StreamReader(csvFilePath)) {
  using(var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFilePath)) {
   string line;
   bool isFirstLine = true;

   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
    if (!isFirstLine && !line.StartsWith("F|")) {
     sw.WriteLine(line);
    } else if (line.StartsWith("F|")) {
     foundFooter = true;
     break; // we're now on the footer line, so don't go any further - sometimes the footer line has another blank line after it
    }

    isFirstLine = false;
   }
  }
 }

 if (foundFooter) {
  // the file did NOT previously have its header and footer removed, but that has been done just now, so go ahead and save the modified file
  File.Delete(csvFilePath);
  File.Move(tempFilePath, csvFilePath);
 } else {
  // the file previously had its header and footer removed, so do not change it
  File.Delete(tempFilePath);
 }

 GrantWideOpenFilePermissions(csvFilePath);
}
```

Somewhere in there, the file permissions got removed. So I reapply the permissions with this, right after:

```
public static void GrantWideOpenFilePermissions(string fullPath) {
   DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
   DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
   dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
   dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
}
```

Mystery solved. Sorry to bother everyone with programmer error, but this might help someone with a similar problem.